# Why does commit exclusion through caret notation not actually exclude commits in command prompt?

Tags: git, cmd

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges:

> Commit Exclusions
>
> ^ (caret) Notation
>
> To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a prefix ^ notation is used. E.g. ^r1 r2 means commits reachable from r2 but exclude the ones
>   reachable from r1 (i.e. r1 and its ancestors).

I have a testing repository on which I have tried this syntax out. For the purposes of this question, it consists of three normal commits:

```
git log --pretty=oneline topic1
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1
b5803f6c59cbc9ae6b4bba81b0d5ad8cfbd8f23a start of topic 1
75400b34ebc0936dd28513c686c8adb526f063e6 (origin/master) Initial Commit
```

Let's try excluding all but the most recent commit:

```
git log --pretty=oneline ^topic1~ topic1
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1
b5803f6c59cbc9ae6b4bba81b0d5ad8cfbd8f23a start of topic 1
75400b34ebc0936dd28513c686c8adb526f063e6 (origin/master) Initial Commit
```

It didn't work. That seems strange, given that we're following the caret notation perfectly. Suppose we try using the commit hash instead:

```
git log --pretty=oneline ^b5803 topic1
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1
b5803f6c59cbc9ae6b4bba81b0d5ad8cfbd8f23a start of topic 1
75400b34ebc0936dd28513c686c8adb526f063e6 (origin/master) Initial Commit
```

Still not working. By contrast, other notations work as expected:

```
git log --pretty=oneline topic1 --not topic1~
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1

git log --pretty=oneline topic1~..topic1
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1
```

Why does the caret exclusion notation not behave in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say which platform you are using. But let me guess: You are on Windows and you are typing these commands in the Windows command line prompt, CMD.

CMD is a strange beast. In particular, the caret `^` is an escape character of some sort. To pass a single caret to the invoked program, you must type two carets on the command line:

```
git log --pretty=oneline ^^topic1~ topic1
```

I generally stay away from `^` and use `--not` instead:

```
git log --pretty=oneline topic1 --not topic1~
```

But it has its own caveats, most importantly, its effect extends to all subsequent refs given on the command line, not just the next one. That is the reason why the two ref specifications have to be swapped compared to your original example.

Answer (score 0):

Command prompt treats the caret symbol as an escape character - that is, a caret causes command prompt to interpret the character following it as a literal. This causes the caret to have no effect in this instance. In command prompt, you can use two carets (^^) whenever you would normally use one:

```
git log --pretty=oneline ^^topic1~ topic1
77ffe1ada25be4b465be9fc9b46f63981ecc8b16 (origin/topic1, topic1) second commit of topic 1
```